Javascript - Download xls file served from backend in blob format
I have a backend service writted in Java that will power the vue frontend app. I need to start the download of a file when it will be provided from the backend. At the moment I've noticed that the response fro the backend that will provide the file is an object. The object have this structure:
{
 data: "..." //This is supposed to be a blob
}

How I can convert the response to an xls file correctly? I've tried to pass it to the File consctructor but the resulting file seems corrupted.
getXlsFile(data)
 .then( (res) => {
   let file = new File([res?.data], 'report.xls');
   ...
  })

Not sure if I need to convert the response in a blob again?
UPDATE
I saw from the dev console in the network tab that the response is in base64 format, but what I see if i do a console log of the response are a strange set of chars. I've tried to convert the rsponse from the network tab using an online tool and seems correct the resulting file.
How I can check if the response is in base64 and eventually create a blob from it for the download?

You'll need to use a library on the client that can parse the XLS data.

is there a library in particular I can use?No other way to take the response and parse it without library? Initially a library was used to generate xls but now all is managed from backend so I just need to let the user download the file

AFAIK there's nothing built into JavaScript that can parse XLS data, so you need to use a library. I don't know any libraries in particular, I'm sure Google can help you.

You could also parse it on the back end and send JSON to the client.

So I will need to parse the data in any case if I understand the point

Actually, I didn't notice that you say you want to download the file, not process it in the application. You don't need to parse it if you're just passing it through.

If we talk about HTTP-interaction between client and server we have only 2 options - the response is either binary (blob/arraybuffer) or a string. There's no such option like "a structure described by string that has a binary data as node/value". So there's just no way a server can send you the structure you described without some additional client logic. Therefore you better figure out or describe what actually your server returns you. Also I hope you understand that XLS/XLSX couldn't be stringified since its binary by design

@lucifer63 I'm getting the blob from the backend. I need only to save it as xls as is, we use exceljs inside the project but I don't think the library is able to save the file in the correct way from a blob

You can try to use the javascript Blob to convert and then force the file dowload
This is a working function in my utils.js (this downloads a txt file from a textarea element)
function generateTextFile(textareaElement, filenameWithoutExtension) {
    var textToWrite = textareaElement.val();
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], { type: 'text/plain' });
    var fileNameToSaveAs = filenameWithoutExtension + ".txt" //Your filename;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}

You should try something like this: (not tested)
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([blobFromYourBackend], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "myexcel.xls" //Your filename;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();

Other option to try:
var textToWrite = [blobFromYourBackend];
var l = document.createElement("a");
l.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8," + textToWrite;
l.setAttribute("download", "myexcel.xls");
l.click();


I've tried but the resulting file will be aways corrupted, excel give a warning about this and sometimes inside the file I will find the undefined text in the first cell.

I've added other option for you to try. Not sure if the charset part is needed

After some research into the code I've found the problem. Axios was converting the response ito json. I've modified the response type to blob and now I'm able to download the file
